# Basic Profile Lookup always returning no contact found

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I've recently begun learning Javascript using the tutorials on freecodecamp and there's this challenge I've been stuck on for a few hours now.

The function always returns 'No contact found' and I don't understand why. If someone were to explain it to me and correct my code, I'd be grateful.

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  for (var i=0; contacts.length>i; i++) {

    if (contacts[i][firstName]==firstName) {
      if (contacts.i.prop.hasOwnProperty()===true) {
        return contacts.i.prop;
      } else { return "No such property";
     }
    } 
      return "No such contact"; }
}

lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName");
```

Comment: Exchange all bracket notation with dot notation and all dot notation with bracket notation and itll work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Explanation**

1. **Typo error** change like this `contacts[i]['firstName']` instead of  `contacts[i][firstName]`.you are missing to match the `keyname` of `obj`.for your way its calling like

   `contacts[i][Akira] == false statement`  so only it always go else statement
2. Do the object  key call method with `obj[key]` instead of `obj.key` .Beacuse all are varible not with direct name of the key
3. second one `hasownproperty(varible)` .you are not mention which word to check with that object

```js
var contacts = [ { "firstName": "Akira", "lastName": "Laine", "number": "0543236543", "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"] }, { "firstName": "Harry", "lastName": "Potter", "number": "0994372684", "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"] }, { "firstName": "Sherlock", "lastName": "Holmes", "number": "0487345643", "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"] }, { "firstName": "Kristian", "lastName": "Vos", "number": "unknown", "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"] } ];

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {

  for (var i=0; contacts.length>i; i++) {
    if (contacts[i]['firstName']==firstName) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === true) {
        return contacts[i][prop];
      } 
      else {
      return "No such property";
     }
    } 
      return "No such contact"; }
}

console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "lastName"));
```

Comment: May leave away the ===true

Comment: @Jonasw ya..you are right.But for the purpose of understanding is needed .

Comment: `contacts[i].firstName` is just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `Array.prototype.find()` for this:

```
function findByProp(list, val, prop) {
  let found = list.find(el => el[prop] === val);
  return found ? found[prop] : "No contact found";
}
```

```js
var contacts = [{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];

function findByProp(list, val, prop) {
  let found = list.find(el => el[prop] === val);
  return found ? found[prop] : "No contact found";
}

console.log(findByProp(contacts, "Akira", "firstName"));
console.log(findByProp(contacts, "foo", "firstName"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {

    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {

        if ((name == contacts[i].firstName)) {
            if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else
                return "No such property";
        }
        
        if (i == contacts.length - 1) return "No such contact";
    }
}
```